# Python add up 2 unevenly sized 2d arrays at given index as center

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Given 2 arrays, for example:

```
main_arr = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
])

small_arr = np.array([
    [2, 2, 2],
    [2, 0, 2],
    [2, 2, 2]
])

result_arr = np.array([
    [2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
    [2, 1, 2, 0, 0],
    [2, 2, 4, 2, 2],
    [0, 0, 2, 1, 2],
    [0, 0, 2, 2, 2]
])
```

How to efficiently add up *small_arr* into the *main_arr* where center for merging is some known index (in this example number ones).Is there is any handy tool for this operation?

In my specific case, I have hundreds of thousands of indexes and need to perform this same operation. So ideally the solution should be looping process that runs through the set of indexes.

Comment: explain _Why_ the result looks what it looks like. Explain your "given index"

Comment: explain what to do if the "1" sits in a way so that not all overlayed numbers of _small_arr_  are inside the bigger one - f.e.:  `[1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]`

Comment: what you want to do is a kind of 2d "kernel" operation on the values that are 1 - you can look / research that  f.e. https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/2d-convolution-using-python-numpy-43442ff5f381 - it is f.e. used in image computation for edgefinding, smoothing, etc

Comment: The point of the question is, to simply add a small array into the big one at specific indexes. In the example I used 1s as a position, where the index would be extracted. The index then is used as a place where the small array is added. So where 1 is in the main_arr, the small_arr is added. This creating a combined grid. 1 doesnt change because values 0 is added onto it.

Comment: I think a simple 2D convolution should do what you want (see my update)

Comment: @XDOL  What happens if a 1 is on the first row of your bigger array - the smaller 3x3 if centered on top of the 1 would "hang over" by 1 row into nothingness ... an **edge-case** so to say ....

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yes an edge case is a problem indeed. However in my case I can fortunately ignore that, because in my case there can't be any values at the edges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### 2D convolution

###### simple example 0/1 only

If you want to add the values where you have the 1s, use a 2D convolution:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
out = convolve2d(main_arr, small_arr, mode='same')+main_arr
```

output:

```
array([[2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 2, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 4, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 2, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2]])
```

###### more complex example

```
main_arr  = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0, 9, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 9, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
])

small_arr = np.array([
    [2, 2, 2],
    [2, 0, 2],
    [2, 2, 2]
])

from scipy.signal import convolve2d

convolve2d((main_arr==1).astype(bool), small_arr, mode='same')+main_arr
```

output:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  0,  9,  0],
       [ 2,  2,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  9,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  2,  1,  2],
       [-1,  0,  2,  2,  2]])
```

##### older answer

Assuming you want to add from the positions 0,0 and 2,2, you could use:

```
main_arr  = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
])

small_arr = np.array([
    [2, 2, 2],
    [2, 0, 2],
    [2, 2, 2]
])

x,y = small_arr.shape
main_arr[0:x, 0:y] += small_arr    # actually main_arr[0:0+x, 0:0+y]
main_arr[2:2+x, 2:2+y] += small_arr
```

output:

```
array([[2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 2, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 4, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 2, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Comment: On a side note for future reader, this solution will only work if `main_arr` is populated with 1 and 0, 1 being the place you want to add the kernel.

Comment: @NiziL yes, otherwise you can use `(main_arr==1).astype(bool)` to perform the convolution ;)

Comment: The 1s and 0s are only for demo purposes. The solution in reality needs to work with tuple of indexes. But your solution could be used if I converted all values on each index with 1

Comment: @XDOLK009 see the more complex example, would this work for you?

Comment: @mozway Yes thank you, that solution is simple and good :). This and example from Nizil are indeed the right choises. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume `small_arr` is always square, with an odd dimension (so we have a center).

```py
indexes = [(1,1), (3,3)]
offset = small_arr.shape[0] // 2
for x, y in indexes:
  main_arr[x-offset:x+offset+1, y-offset:y+offset+1] += small_arr
```

As pointed out in the comments, this still not solve case where your index is "on the border" of `main_arr`.

Comment: Border lines can be neglected in my case, but yes it's a valid point. That could be a problem in some other cases

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know the indicies, you just have to go over every position that is a neighbor of that index. So you have to find the coordinates using the indices first, which will be a list of tuples. Assuming the small array always is a 3x3 matrix, you can do the following:

```
coordinates = [(x_1,y_1), ... , (x_n,y_n)]

for(co in coordinates) {

  x = co[0]
  y = co[1]
  result_arr[x][y + 1] = result_arr[x][y + 1] + small_arr[x][y + 1]
  result_arr[x][y - 1] = result_arr[x][y - 1] + small_arr[x][y - 1]
  result_arr[x + 1][y] = result_arr[x + 1][y] + small_arr[x + 1][y]
  result_arr[x + 1][y + 1] = result_arr[x + 1][y + 1] + small_arr[x + 1][y + 1]
  result_arr[x + 1][y - 1] = result_arr[x + 1][y - 1] + small_arr[x + 1][y - 1]
  result_arr[x - 1][y] = result_arr[x - 1][y] + small_arr[x - 1][y]
  result_arr[x - 1][y + 1] = result_arr[x - 1][y + 1] + small_arr[x - 1][y + 1]
  result_arr[x - 1][y - 1] = result_arr[x - 1][y - 1] + small_arr[x - 1][y - 1]
```

Comment: My "small_arr" isn't always 3x3, but is always predefined